# Segmented C# file downloader

Tags: c#, download, httpwebresponse

Have been trying to write a program in C# that downloads a file using multiple segments at once like most download managers, and I've run into the issue that the files downloaded are corrupted. E.g., I download a video and it plays for 2 seconds then WMP says it's unplayable.

I hexedited the downloaded file and it appears there are sections of zerobytes scattered throughout the file, anyone have any ideas why? VS reports no errors.

`getPart()` is called for each segment in a separate thread.

```
public long start;
public long end;
public int thread;
public Form1 handle;
public myFile handler;
public void getPart()
{
    log("getting part " + start.ToString() + "," + end.ToString());
    HttpWebRequest part = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(handler.url);
    part.AddRange((int)start,(int) end);
    HttpWebResponse pr = (HttpWebResponse)part.GetResponse();
    Stream rstream = pr.GetResponseStream();
    log("Beginning part " + start.ToString());
    int totalbytes = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    int x = rstream.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
    while (x > 0)
    {
        handler.writeFile(buffer, (int)(totalbytes + start), x);
        totalbytes += x;
        x = rstream.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
    }
    log(start.ToString() + "-byte start part done...");
    rstream.Close();
    pr.Close();
    handler.partDone(thread);
    return;
}

public void writeFile(byte[] buffer, int start, int size)
{
    mFileStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    mFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, size);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Well I've figured it out, just thought I'd leave an answer for anyone having similar issues. A lock is required around the file writing stream.

```
public void writeFile(byte[] buffer, int start, int size)
    {
        mFileStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        mFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, size);
        return;
    }
```

becomes

```
public void writeFile(byte[] buffer, int start, int size)
    {
        lock (mFileStream)
        {
        mFileStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        mFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, size);
        return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, just wondering, the downloading is not in parallel, right?

Comment: I guess not, `start` and `end` is outside the method. with this you can play the video while downloading.