# Download large file in small chunks in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, websocket

I need to download some file which is more than 25 MB large, but my network only allow to request a file of 25 MB only.

I am using following code

```
  const long DefaultSize = 26214400;
    long Chunk = 26214400;
    long offset = 0;
    byte[] bytesInStream;
    public void Download(string url, string filename)
    {
        long size = Size(url);
        int blocksize = Convert.ToInt32(size / DefaultSize);
        int remainder = Convert.ToInt32(size % DefaultSize);
        if (remainder > 0) { blocksize++; }

        FileStream fileStream = File.Create(@"D:\Download TEST\" + filename);
        for (int i = 0; i < blocksize; i++)
        {
            if (i == blocksize - 1)
            {
                Chunk = remainder;

            }

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.AddRange(Convert.ToInt32(offset), Convert.ToInt32(Chunk+offset));
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            // StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());


            using (Stream responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                bytesInStream = new byte[Chunk];
                responseStream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);
                // Use FileStream object to write to the specified file
                fileStream.Seek((int)offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                fileStream.Write(bytesInStream,0, bytesInStream.Length);
            }
            offset += Chunk;

        }
        fileStream.Close();

    }
    public long Size(string url)
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "HEAD";
        System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        resp.Close();
        return resp.ContentLength;

    }
```

It is properly writing content on disk but content is not working

Comment: I can't really supply an answer, but are you able to step through the code? I would suggest scaling down all your numbers (e.g. setting a max chunk size of 10 bytes and a download file size of 25 bytes), then stepping through. With smaller chunks involved it may be easier to spot where you're going wrong.

Comment: did you get any final solution, and ***working*** ? With answer: `it still not working` you say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check how much was read before write, something like this (and you don't need to remember the offset to seek, the seek is automatic when you write):

```
int read;
do
{
    read = responseStream.Read(bytesInStream, 0, (int)bytesInStream.Length);
    if (read > 0)
        fileStream.Write(bytesInStream, 0, read);
}
while(read > 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar SO questions that might help you 
[Segmented C# file downloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831279/segmented-c-sharp-file-downloader)

and

[How to open multiple connections to download single file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397060/how-to-open-multiple-connections-to-download-single-file)

Also this code project article
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/307548/Resume-Suppoert-Downloading

Answer (score 1):

Range is zero based and you should subtract 1 from upper bound.

```
request.Headers.Range = new System.Net.Http.Headers.RangeHeaderValue(offset, chunkSize + offset - 1);
```

I published correct code fragment at the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48019611/1099716

Answer (score 0):

Akka streams can help download file in small chunks from a System.IO.Stream using multithreading. https://getakka.net/articles/intro/what-is-akka.html

The Download method will append the bytes to the file starting with long fileStart. If the file does not exist, fileStart value must be 0.

```
using Akka.Actor;
using Akka.IO;
using Akka.Streams;
using Akka.Streams.Dsl;
using Akka.Streams.IO;

private static Sink<ByteString, Task<IOResult>> FileSink(string filename)
{
    return Flow.Create<ByteString>()
        .ToMaterialized(FileIO.ToFile(new FileInfo(filename), FileMode.Append), Keep.Right);
}

private async Task Download(string path, Uri uri, long fileStart)
{
    using (var system = ActorSystem.Create("system"))
    using (var materializer = system.Materializer())
    {
       HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
       request.AddRange(fileStart);

       using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
       {
           Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

           await StreamConverters.FromInputStream(() => stream, chunkSize: 1024)
               .RunWith(FileSink(path), materializer);
       }
    }
}
```