# Download large files using a memorystream

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm writing a generic handler which is used to download rather large (400+ mb) files from a secured FTP server. I got my code working on small test images by copying the response stream to a MemoryStream and then binary write the bytes array.

My code looks like this (DownloadFile.ashx):

```
// Set correct path
string path = ftpHelper.GetCompletePath();
path += "/" + loginId + "/" + folderName + "/" + fileName;

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
request.UsePassive = false;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpHelper.Username, ftpHelper.Password);

byte[] fileBytes = null;

using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            if (responseStream != null) responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
 }

if (fileBytes.Length > 0)
{
     context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
     context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
}

request.Abort();

context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Question is: on a live webserver with 8gb of ram (it's currently using ~60% of it's existing ram since is quite a large website! It might need a ram upgrade ;-)) would it be safe to make the CopyTo() and use a MemoryStream with such large files?

I know that I could just set the download link on the client directly to the FTP server by [ftp://username:password@path.com](ftp://username%3apassword@path.com), but the content on the FTP is password secured for a reason as there's some sensitive data on it.

So, is a memorystream safe to use with such large files? And if not: is there any other way of doing this, that I have overlooked?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MemoryStream` is "safe" to use for large files. However, you will be loading the entire file into memory, and it will remain there until Garbage Collection determines it a good time to recycle that memory.

8GB of RAM is plenty for a "medium" load production server. This is, of course, objective, but if a single low-medium traffic WebApp is using more than 8GB of RAM then some design decisions should be revised.

There are two options to avoid loading the entire remote file into memory:

1. Write it to a local file on disk, and serve that file back to the WebApp client
2. Do a chunked write directly to the Response stream

Option 2 could be something like:

```
//...
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    Response.BufferOutput= false;   // to prevent buffering 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
    int bytesRead = 0; 
    while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)  
    { 
         Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); 
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and code example! I copied your code and it works right out of the box - and it's blazing fast! :-) With my CopyTo() memorystream logic, it took a second or so to actually start downloading the image.

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to "just work", that's a nice bonus! I'd investigate altering the buffer size too. You could tune it to match the throughput from your ftp server; this could have another impact of the overall speed of the operation.

Comment: when i use this the file i opened in binary mode with firefox ! how can ensure to start downloading ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a memory stream should be fine. Remember you don't need to write the entire file at once, keep writing data till you've returned it all and then close the response.

Take a look at a this question to get some idea of how you might return days in chunks instead [Download large file in small chunks in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566302/download-large-file-in-small-chunks-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response, Ian :-) I found this one as well: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;812406 (the C# example in the middle of the page) So basically I can skip the memory stream by doing it like this? I'll have a go at it!

Comment: @bomortensen yep, generally any stream, just write bits at a time

Answer (score 0):

```
    void WriteFile(string path, string filename)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            //response is HttpListenerContext.Response... 
            Response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename); 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
            int read; 
            while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                Response.OutputStream.Flush(); //seems to have no effect
            } 
            Response.OutputStream.Close();
        }
        File.Delete(path);
        Response.End();
    }
```