# Downloading large files without loading the whole file into memory first

Tags: asp-classic, streaming, download

I have a classic asp site that I am using to download files and to this point the files have been quite small (<5mb).  But now we want to use the site for much larger files upwards of 2GB.  The code below works but does not prompt for the user to "open/save" until the entire file is loaded into memory.  So on a large file the site appears to hang for several minutes before prompting the user.  I'd like for the popup to occur right away if possible.  Any ideas?

```
Set HttpReq = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 'works
HttpReq.open "GET", "http://myaspnetwebapiservice/api/values/1", False
HttpReq.send

Response.BinaryWrite HttpReq.responseBody
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566302/download-large-file-in-small-chunks-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Use **Range** header to request part of the large file. Download one by one part, and merge the response bodies. see [Range Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233).

for example:

```
HttpReq.setRequestHeader "Range","bytes=0-100000"
```

Or use [responseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759211(v=vs.85).aspx) property to handle the response.