# Download video files at fast speed from http URL with size greater than 1 GB

Tags: c#, wpf, video

I am trying to implement an application wherein I have to download large sized videos from HTTP web server having a URL. By clicking on URL the video download should start. The video should be downloaded within 10 to 15 seconds.

I tried using Web Client but this takes hours to download single video file. I also searched for APIs to download the videos at fast speed but I only got source specific APIs like Google Drive, YouTube.

I searched for JDownloader API to incorporate with C# and WPF but there is not enough documentation as to how to use it in Windows Or web applications.

Comment: may this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566302/download-large-file-in-small-chunks-in-c-sharp

Comment: You can write your own downloader which uses `Range` header of http requests and downloads many parts in parallel.

Comment: @un-lucky Thanks for providing the links. I need to download the files with the extension present in the URL and not manually providing the file extension.

Comment: @Eser Thanks.Can you please provide sample code as I am new to this?